# resources routing mixup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a mystery in my routes:

```
resources :organizations

root :to => 'users#index'

devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registration', :sessions => 'users/session', :confirmations => 'users/confirmation'}
```

Now, if I try to reach `/organizations/1` it works.

If I try `/organizations` or `/organizations/new`

I get the same error for both cases: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"organizations"}`

which path I never requested. And which path exists btw.

Is there anything that can intercept routes and do some hidden redirect in rails (or devise)?

**UPDATE**

Here are the routes:

```
       organizations GET    /organizations(.:format)              organizations#index
                     POST   /organizations(.:format)              organizations#create
    new_organization GET    /organizations/new(.:format)          organizations#new
   edit_organization GET    /organizations/:id/edit(.:format)     organizations#edit
        organization GET    /organizations/:id(.:format)          organizations#show
                     PUT    /organizations/:id(.:format)          organizations#update
                     DELETE /organizations/:id(.:format)          organizations#destroy
                root        /                                     users#index
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)              users/session#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)              users/session#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)             users/session#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)         devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)        devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)             devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)               users/registration#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                      users/registration#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)              users/registration#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                 users/registration#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                      users/registration#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                      users/registration#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)         users/confirmation#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)     users/confirmation#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)         users/confirmation#show
             user_unlock POST   /users/unlock(.:format)               devise/unlocks#create
         new_user_unlock GET    /users/unlock/new(.:format)           devise/unlocks#new
                         GET    /users/unlock(.:format)               devise/unlocks#show
```

**UPDATE**

Here are OrganizationsController and ApplicationController:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    new
    render 'organizations/new'
  end

  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
  end
end
```

and

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    accounts_path
  end

  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do |exception|
    flash[:error] = exception.message
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the organization's new.html.erb view

```
<%= semantic_form_for @organization, :url => organization_path do |f| %>

    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%=  f.input :country %>
        <%=  f.input :type, :as => :select, :label => t(:g_type), :collection =>     [[t(:g_company),"Company"],[t(:g_person),"Person"]] %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.actions %>
<% end %>
```

**UPDATE**

I also checked that the routes are well defined and they seem to be:

```
>> r = Rails.application.routes
#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x3dbea00>
>> r.recognize_path("/organizations/new")
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"organizations"}
>> r.recognize_path("/organizations/1")
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"organizations", :id=>"1"}
```

Comment: Can you post the result of `rake routes` ?

Comment: Sure, just added it to the main post.

Comment: routes look fine, did you restart your server?

Comment: Like a million times. (just retried, jsut for you). If it can be of any use, I have some other resources (like accounts,, etc.). And all routes for all controllers behave the same as described in the post.

Comment: What's in your application_controller and organizations_controller? Anything redirecting in there? Any before_filters?

Comment: Post you organizations_controller.rb

Comment: I just added both of them to the main post.

Comment: Try remove from index method 'new'

Comment: `/organizations/new` still yields the error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"organizations"}`

Comment: just a thought. Shift the root route to the last. ie after all other routes and devise before organisation routes

Comment: Jus tried. Same problem.

Comment: Well, anyone? I've been banging my head for hours on this. :(

Comment: Okay, I removed the `devise` gem and routes are working again. So there definitely is a routing messup inside devise! Now, "where" is the question. I've been so far unable to trace the redirection using breakpoints and steps. I'll keep on trying. Any idea is welcome....

Answer (score 0):

in your "organisations/new.html.erb" standard a link is created to `organisation_path(@organisation)`. And that one does not exist, because you don't have a show for organisations.

Update: if the path-helper was used, the error was pointing there, but problably `link_to "Back", @organisation` is used...

Comment: I did try adding a `show` action in my organizations controller. The error still shows up. Now, the redirect_to :back is triggered by a CanCan::AccessDenied exception. Why would tha be called?

Comment: I added a breakboint in the `rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied` and it's never triggered when requesting `/organizations/new`.

Comment: 1. First remove the CanCan funcitonality, to see if that's causing it. 2. Post your new.html.erb, to check if that has erroneous links.

Comment: ok I removed Cancan (commented the gem, the class and the code in application_controller.rb. Problem still here. I added the new.html.erb to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

u have defined index as

```
def index
  new 
  render 'organizations/new' 
end
```

if u dont specify the file name to be rendered, the file with method_name is rendered. since u have specified **organizations/new**, i guess u want to display form for new organization
do u want to redirect to new organization form? if yes, then add

```
redirect_to new_organization_path and return
```

If u want to to display the list of organizations and also accept the new organization data on the same page, u can do so

```
def new
  @organizations = Organization.all
  @organization = Organization.new
end
```

and in ur new form

```
= form_for(@organization, :url => organizations_path, :method => :post) do |f|
```

it should be **organzations_path**

Comment: Well, I don't see what this has to do with routes and the show methods. What you describe is the standard rails way, which I follow (I don't want to redirect I want to render in my index action). Moreover I don't get what you say in the last post: Why should I spell **organizations_path** as **organzations_path**?!

Comment: it should be organizations_path and not organization_path. Plural.

Comment: Well, I removed the whole code from new.html.erb and problem still arises. Don't know what more I can do...I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Your logs will tell you what it tries to render, maybe it tries to render another file than you expect. One tip: organization_path (single form) always needs a parameter, otherwise you get strange problems.